# gnome-terminal change tab color ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

I'm using the gnome-terminal in ubuntu 19.04 quite alot. When using multiple tabs black letters on white background this looks like the picture below:

[image: screenshot of gnome-terminal]

I think that the tab bar is (depending on the monitor setting and the lighting) barely readable, because it consists of grey letters on black background and its hard to see which is the active tab. Is there a way to change the color scheme to make this text more readable and to better highlight the current active tab? This is the same question as in 
[Customizing terminal tab color in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990548/customizing-terminal-tab-color-in-ubuntu-17-10) or https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/highlighting-the-active-tab-in-gnome-terminal/ but for ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: your issue here, is that you prefer white theme to night theme (clearly, since you use black text on white background for your terminal, my retinas) in that case the solution would be for you to go all the way and pick a white/clear theme for ubuntu. use ubuntu-tweak and try Adwaita or high-contrast (that seems to be your thing) I think it'll suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already tried to change ~/.config/gtk-3.0 but gnome-terminal didn't change a bit.
I have konsole in which is very easy to change the tabs problem you got.

I have made these changes:
[image: Konsole Settings]

In which konsole.css is:

```
QTabBar::tab:selected {
background: lightblue;
color: black;
font: bold;   }
```

And konsole looks like:

[image: How Konsole looks]

And you can play around settings and find out what you like the most :)

Answer (score 1):

Succeeded in fixing gnome-terminal tab colors in Mint 21.2 (based on Ubuntu 22.04).

Used [GTK+ Inspector](https://blog.gtk.org/2017/04/05/the-gtk-inspector/) to dig through the CSS tree (had to invoke Inspector by enabling the Menubar; then Help/Inspector).

The CSS can be added to *~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css* - create it if it doesn't exist.

Mine says:

```
.terminal-notebook tab:checked {
    background-color: #555;
}
```