# Change terminal tab color in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, kubuntu, colors

I am exactly looking for the same as these guys:

[How to make selected tab in terminal more prominent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40332/how-to-make-selected-tab-in-terminal-more-prominent)
[Customizing terminal tab color in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990548/customizing-terminal-tab-color-in-ubuntu-17-10)

They use this file:

> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

But I can't find it in my Kubuntu 18.04

Is there any new solution for 18.04 ?

Thanks

Comment: Kubuntu uses a completely different Desktop Environment (KDE) than Ubuntu (GNOME3).  `konsole` is not a GTK application.  It gets its theme from Qt.  You should check the theme settings in KDE Settings or the terminal application itself.  You can use another terminal app if you don't want to use `konsole`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create that file. In the answer of the first link the first step is:

> 1. **Create** the file ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

Comment: I did it. How can I load that config file ?

Comment: do you mean how to edit?

Comment: @totalynotanoob most KDE applications don't use GTK (they use Qt) so unfortunately this probably won't help